# Dump a Cloud SQL MySQL instance from an external server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-replica) guide to configure an external instance replicating a Cloud SQL MySQL instance. Unfortunately something went wrong or I'm misinterpreting the concept of "external replica" in gcloud; maybe external means another VM in the gcloud platform, not a VM hosted by another cloud provider?
 For a description of the error and the possible cause please check this other [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/276025/dump-sql-cloud-mysql-instance-for-external-replica).
Now I'm trying to narrow down the issue and finally I noticed that when running `mysqldump` from the external VM with the `--master-data` option it hangs forever.

E.g. the following works:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction -h x.x.x.x -u root -p db_name table_name
```

while this hangs:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --master-data -h x.x.x.x -u root -p db_name table_name
```

Has anyone managed to successfully configure an external slave replicating from a Cloud SQL MySQL instance?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation :

[Replication in Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#external-read-replicas)

> External read replicas External read replicas are external MySQL
> instances that replicate from a Cloud SQL primary instance. For
> example, a MySQL instance running on Compute Engine is considered an
> external instance.
>
> External read replicas have the following restrictions:
>
> **Replicating to a MySQL instance hosted by another cloud platform might
> not be possible; check the documentation from the other provider**

Therefore is important to check the documentation of the other cloud provider.

Comment: Thank you, useful answer, but I had already read that (anyway +1 for pointing it out).